# Interceptor doesn't work when call a method inside another method in same class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, castle-dynamicproxy

I have used `Autofac` `DynamicProxy` to implement cache for methods. But inceptor doesn't work when call a method inside another method in same class. for example I have Class `ClassRepository` as:

```
public class ClassRepository : IClassRepository
{
    [Cache]
    public async Task<List<string>> Method1()
    {
       //Do some thing
    }

    [Cache]
    public async Task<List<string>> Method2()
    {
       var methodCall = await Method1()
    }

}
```

And my inceptor is like this:

```
public class CacheInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly ICache cache;
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> InProcessKeys = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();
    public CacheInterceptor(ICache cache)
    {
        this.cache = cache;
    }
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        ProcessInterceptAsync(invocation).Wait();
        
    }

    private async Task ProcessInterceptAsync(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var proceed = invocation.CaptureProceedInfo();

        

        var cacheAttribute = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget.GetCustomAttributes<CacheAttribute>(false).FirstOrDefault();

        if (cacheAttribute == null)
        {
            proceed.Invoke();
            return;
        }
        var key = GetCacheKey(invocation);
        ExistKeyCheck(key);

        var methodReturnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType;
        dynamic cacheResult = GetCache(key, cacheAttribute, methodReturnType);

        if (cacheResult != null)
        {
            invocation.ReturnValue = cacheResult;
            InProcessKeys.Remove(key, out _);
            return;
        }

        InProcessKeys.TryAdd(key, true);

        proceed.Invoke();
        var delegateType = GetDelegateType(invocation);
        switch (delegateType)
        {
            case MethodType.Synchronous:
                break;
            case MethodType.AsyncAction:
                await InterceptAsync((Task)invocation.ReturnValue);
                break;
            case MethodType.AsyncFunction:
                var method = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget;
                var isAsync = method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute)) != null;
                if (isAsync && typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType))
                {
                    var methodResult = await InterceptAsync((dynamic)invocation.ReturnValue);
                    invocation.ReturnValue = methodResult;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (invocation.ReturnValue == null)
        {
            InProcessKeys.Remove(key, out _);
            return;
        }

        await cache.SetAsync(key, invocation.ReturnValue, cacheAttribute.Duration, cacheAttribute.CacheInstance, cacheAttribute.Extend);
        InProcessKeys.Remove(key, out _);
    }

    private dynamic GetCache(string key, CacheAttribute cacheAttribute, Type methodReturnType)
    {
        var finalType = methodReturnType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var getMethod = typeof(DistributedCache).GetMethods().Where(x => x.IsGenericMethod && x.Name =="Get").FirstOrDefault().MakeGenericMethod(finalType);
        var cacheResult = (dynamic)getMethod.Invoke(cache, new object[] { key, cacheAttribute.CacheInstance });

        if (cacheResult is null) return null;
        if (methodReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
            return Task.FromResult(cacheResult);
        else
            return cacheResult;
    }

    private static void ExistKeyCheck(string key)
    {
        if (InProcessKeys.Any(x => x.Key==key))
        {
            Task.Delay(50).Wait();
            var counter = 0;
            while (InProcessKeys.Any(x => x.Key==key) && counter < 10)
            {
                Task.Delay(50).Wait();
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task InterceptAsync(Task task) => await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

    private static async Task<T> InterceptAsync<T>(Task<T> task) => await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    private MethodType GetDelegateType(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var returnType = invocation.Method.ReturnType;
        if (returnType == typeof(Task))
            return MethodType.AsyncAction;
        if (returnType.IsGenericType && returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
            return MethodType.AsyncFunction;
        return MethodType.Synchronous;
    }
    private enum MethodType
    {
        Synchronous,
        AsyncAction,
        AsyncFunction
    }

    private static string GetCacheKey(IInvocation invocation)
    {

        var key = invocation.Arguments.Length > 0 ? $"-{invocation.Arguments[0]}" : "";

        var cacheKey = $"{invocation.TargetType.FullName.Replace('.', ':')}" +
                       $".{invocation.Method.Name}" +
                       $"{key}";
        return cacheKey;
    }
}
```

and My autofac module is like this:

```
public class RepositoryModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            
            builder.RegisterType<CacheInterceptor>();
            var flightDataAccess = Assembly.Load("DataAccess");
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(flightDataAccess)
                .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope().InterceptedBy(typeof(CacheInterceptor)).EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
                
        }
    }
```

When I resolve IClassRepository and call Method2, CacheInterceptor execute successfully for Method2. but inside Method2 I called Method1 and it doesn't work for Method1. I'll appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Are both methods part of the interface ?

Comment: Yes, both of them are part of interface. I change both method to `virtual` too. but interceptor doesn't find out that another method called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I could solve it. At first I had to change my methods to `virtual` methods.

> Note: for private methods I change them to `protected virtual`

Final change Is :

```
public class ClassRepository : IClassRepository
{
    [Cache]
    public virtual async Task<List<string>> Method1()
    {
       //Do some thing
    }

    [Cache]
    public virtual async Task<List<string>> Method2()
    {
       var methodCall = await Method1()
    }

}
```

In `Module` class I changed `EnableInterfaceInterceptors` to `EnableClassInterceptors` and final change is :

```
    public class RepositoryModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            
            builder.RegisterType<CacheInterceptor>();
            var flightDataAccess = Assembly.Load("DataAccess");
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(flightDataAccess)
                .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope().InterceptedBy(typeof(CacheInterceptor)).EnableClassInterceptors();
                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
public async void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
...
invocation.Proceed();
```

You need to develop a solution without `async void`. Take a look at [the docs](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy-async-interception.md#using-invocationproceed-in-combination-with-asyncawait), which should give you a good starting point. You'll need to set `ReturnValue` and call `CaptureProceedInfo`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, I changed my code and use `CaptureProceedInfo` but still I have problem with second method

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari: Please update your question with the updated code.

Comment: I updated my question and post whole interceptor with all details

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari: You can't call `Wait()` like that. You'll need to structure it so that `Intercept` is naturally synchronous, and the only `async` portions are within methods whose tasklike results are (synchronously) assigned to `ReturnValue`.

Comment: Try getting it working with just one asynchronous return type first (e.g., `Task`), and then handle adding the other return types.